# Why is this for loop appending the same value on each cycle?

Tags: python

I am creating a program, which through differentiation, can return the coordinates and nature of any stationary points, given an equation.

My whole program so far is:

```
equation = input("y=")

expression_list = []

for i in equation:
    expression_list.append(i)


def derive(expression):
    
    global derivation
    derivation = []


    for i in expression:
        if i == "x" and int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]) != 0:

            derivation.append(int(expression[expression.index(i)-1]) * int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]))
            derivation.append("x")
            derivation.append("^")
            derivation.append(int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]) - 1)

derive(expression_list)

expression_list_1st_derivative = derivation

print(expression_list_1st_derivative)
```

The area of the program that I am having trouble with is:

```
def derive(expression):
    
    global derivation
    derivation = []


    for i in expression:
        if i == "x" and int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]) != 0:

            derivation.append(int(expression[expression.index(i)-1]) * int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]))
            derivation.append("x")
            derivation.append("^")
            derivation.append(int(expression[expression.index(i)+2]) - 1)

derive(expression_list)

expression_list_1st_derivative = derivation

print(expression_list_1st_derivative)
```

Using `y=4x^5+3x^4` as an example, I have created this for loop in the hope of giving `["20","x","^","4","12","x","^","3"]` which, if you have studied calculus, you will know as x/dx. I have not included operators yet; that being something I will work on after clearing this hurdle. Currently these lines of code instead give `["20","x","^","4","20","x","^","4"]`. **What changes must I make to get the correct result?**

Comment: `expression.index(i)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `i`, not the index that you're currently thinking of.

Comment: See [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

Your `expression.index(i)` is finding the first position of `i`, not the one that you are currently processing.

Instead you can use `enumerate` and then you have the current index number available.

It would also be better if your function returned a value (here, a list) instead of setting a global variable:

```
def derive(expression):
    derivation = []
    for index, i in enumerate(expression):  # <== note use of "enumerate"
        if i == "x" and int(expression[index+2]) != 0:
            derivation.append(int(expression[index-1]) * int(expression[index+2]))
            derivation.append("x")
            derivation.append("^")
            derivation.append(int(expression[index+2]) - 1)
    return derivation  # <== note return value

expression_list = ["20","x","^","4","12","x","^","3"]  
expression_list_1st_derivative = derive(expression_list)
print(expression_list_1st_derivative)
```